# UNUserNotification not displayed when app is backgrounded

Tags: ios, swift, unusernotificationcenter

I'm trying to get a local notification to fire in the background after a specified delay, but for some reason it's not being presented when being scheduled from my app. I created a bare bones test app to test the behavior in which the same code displays the scheduled notification after the specified delay as expected so I have confirmed that my code is correct. However the same code doesn't produce the same result in my app. I have the correct permissions etc. yet the notification does not show. It will display in foreground, just not when the app is in the background. I've also checked pending notifications after scheduling to see if it's in the queue and it is indeed there. I've searched the code for any reference to `UNUserNotificationCenter.current()` and added breakpoints and comment code to ensure nothing else is interacting with it.

Here is the code to trigger the notification and validate that it has been added to the queue:

```swift
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "Tap to trigger test"

let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)
let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)

UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { (error) in
    print("error", error)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getPendingNotificationRequests(completionHandler: { (requests) in
        print("requests", requests.count)
    })
}
```

And the following is the permissions registration and `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` implementation in my `AppDelegate`:

```swift
public func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    completionHandler(.alert)
}

public func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    print(response)
}

public func registerForPushNotifications() {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { [weak self] granted, error in
        print("Permission granted: \(granted)")
        guard granted else { return }
        self?.getNotificationSettings()
    }
}

public func getNotificationSettings() {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { settings in
        print("Notification settings: \(settings)")
        guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
Permission granted: true
Notification settings: <UNNotificationSettings: 0x280565260; authorizationStatus: Authorized, notificationCenterSetting: Enabled, soundSetting: Enabled, badgeSetting: Enabled, lockScreenSetting: Enabled, carPlaySetting: NotSupported, criticalAlertSetting: NotSupported, alertSetting: Enabled, alertStyle: Banner, providesAppNotificationSettings: No>
error nil 
requests 1
```

I should also add that in testing there has been a few times it has fired randomly. Once when I set a breakpoint in the add request completion block...

Comment: What trace do you get in Console?

Comment: @barbarity See update

Comment: Try to remove all pending notification and try again or restart your device. By the code it should be perfect but it looks like your device is not working properly.

Comment: @barbarity I tried both with no joy. I'm not convinced it's the device though since the test app works fine... Baffled :(

Comment: Unclear what “works” and “doesn’t work” means. What do you expect and what actually happens?

Comment: @matt I updated the question to add more specificity. Appreciate you taking a look

Comment: Have you been able to solve this issue? I am experiencing the same problem. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a body to your content:

```
content.body = "Some content"
```

*I am not sure how did the other sample app work and your main app does not with the same code. But I do not understand also how foreground notifications display for you without content.body*

Comment: @droovers did you try my answer?